# ClassCastException in implementation class

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, classcastexception

Why am I getting the ClassCastException:

Wrapped exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.avt.model.CasePmt
    at com.avt.dao.impl.CasePmtDaoImpl.findAllCasePmt(CasePmtDaoImpl.java:68)
    at com.avt.ViewCasePmtAction.view(ViewCasePmtAction.java:127)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
    at org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.dispatchMethod(DispatchAction.java:280)
    at gov.pbgc.spectrum.util.SpectrumLookupDispatchAction.execute(SpectrumLookupDispatchAction.java:113)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:484)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:274)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1482)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:525)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:763)    
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:856)
```

My implementation class is

```
public List<CasePmt> findAllCasePmt() {
            List list;
            list = getHibernateTemplate().executeFind(new HibernateCallback() {
                    public Object doInHibernate(Session session)
                                    throws HibernateException, SQLException {

                            Query q = session
                                            .getNamedQuery("findAll");
                            return q.list();
                    }
            });
            Iterator it = list.iterator();
            List<CasePmt> l = new ArrayList<CasePmt>();

            CasePmt voObj;
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                    voObj = new CasePmt();

                    Object[] objs = (Object[]) it.next();
                    // System.out.print("\n" + objs[0].toString());

                    if (objs[2] != null) {
                            voObj.setCaseTxNum(objs[1].toString());
                    }


    .......................
                        }
                    l.add(voObj);
            }
            return l;
    }
```

and my action call is :

```
List<CasePmt> CsList =       
             CasePmtBo.getCaseDao().findAllCasePmt();
```

Im getting error in line 68 which is "Object[] objs = (Object[]) it.next();" line.
Why am i getting this issue?

Any inputs..im revisiting this today and facing the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming, you `findAll` query is to retrieve all `CasePmt` objects. In that case, I think you have the issue at line below:

```
 Object[] objs = (Object[]) it.next();
```

**as your iterator will return `CasePmt` object.**

Try casting it to `CasePmt` object as blow:

```
 CasePmt casePmt = (CasePmt)it.next();
```

Comment: I cast it to CasePmt but still in getting the same exception at the same line #.

Comment: @JNPW: Can you please share your `findAll` query?

Comment: Its "Select * from JTL.Case_VW"

Comment: and in entity class: @Entity
 @NamedQueries({
         @NamedQuery(name = "findAll", query = "FROM CasePmt")
 })

Comment: @JNPW: Not sure bout your first query, but if you are using `FROM CasePmt` then it must be `CasePmt` object. To verify, change this : `Object[] objs = (Object[]) it.next();` to `Object objs = it.next();` and then print the class name as `System.out.println(objs.getClass().getName());`

Comment: @JNPW  That is what I am saying. Now try typecasting `objs` to `CasePmt` as `CasePmt casePmt = (CasePmt)objs;`. I hope you have the right `CasePmt` class imported. Some times you have multiple classes(DO, VO) and you are using the wrong one which causes the issue.

Comment: I did cast it to CasePmt but it shows classcastexception at the same line. Im held up now.:(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18835/discussion-between-yogendra-singh-and-jnpw)

Answer (score 1):

In general whenever you have a ClassCastException you do not understand, instead of

```
Object[] objs = (Object[]) it.next();
[...]
```

try

```
Object o = it.next();
if (o instanceof Object[])
{
    Object[] objs = (Object[]) o;
    [...]
}
else if (o != null)
{
    System.out.println("Retrieved object of class " + o.getClass());
    // ... or however you want to inspect the class of the object you retrieved
}
else
    // process null value
```

Answer (score 0):

declayer your list as

```
  List<Object[]> list;
```

if you are getting array of objects and just use it.next() instead of

```
 (Object[]) it.next();
```